# Migrating from SQLAlchemy to MongoDB in Pylons

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mongodb

Is there a migration guide for the the models aspect in pylons, syntax with SQLAlchemy to MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any guide, but if you're looking for something ORM-like, check out Mongokit http://bitbucket.org/namlook/mongokit/wiki/Home.

That said, MongoDB fits Python dictionaries very well. You might not need an ORM at all.

Comment: but i want something to handle object to dicts

Comment: In one of my project, I inherited dict for my models and added a few methods, like save() and load(). If you want to use the dot notation, I think MongoKit takes care of the conversion for you. Or you could simply use properties as a proxy to access the dict.